# Detecting changed user defaults

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have an iPhone app and have implemented local notifications.  The app has a page in Settings that allows a user to schedule notifications a specified number of days in advance of an event.  To make sure that changes to the settings take effect every time a user activates the app, I have the following in my app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [self rescheduleAllNotificationsWithUserNotification:NO];
}
```

The problem is that the call to `rescheduleAllNotificationsWithUserNotification:` takes a few seconds and the app feels a little sluggish on start.

I only need to call `rescheduleAllNotificationsWithUserNotification:` if any of the settings have been changed.  **Is there a way to detect if the user has changed any of the settings between app activations  so I can avoid always rescheduling the notifications**?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for the [`NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification) notification.

You can register to listen to this notification and be informed whenever the user's preferences change.

Comment: This will not work across application restarts.  I.e.,  The application is running, then the user restarts the phone.  The user changes the notification settings after the restart, then restarts the application.  If the app isn't running, then it doesn't get the notification.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a way to put this method call in another thread is possible. performSelectorInBackground is an easy way to do it:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(rescheduleAllNotificationsWithUserNotification:) withObject:NO];
```

That should help you get rid of the laggy performance. You could even use ^blocks, as you seem to be on iOS 4.

Comment: Great idea to put it in a background thread and definitely something I should be doing in all cases when I call this method.  But I'm still looking for a way to avoid the call in the first place if the settings are unchanged since the last time the app was activated.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past, if there are not too many preference values to monitor, is to have alternate versions, sort of "the last time I ran" versions. One set of values is accessible through the Settings application but the other is only set from within the application.

```
NSString *name = (NSString *) CFPreferencesCopyAppValue( (CFStringRef) @"name_preference", kCFPreferencesCurrentApplication );
NSString *nameLastTime = (NSString *) CFPreferencesCopyAppValue( (CFStringRef) @"name_last_execution", kCFPreferencesCurrentApplication );
// Need obvious checks for empty or missing entries, etc., etc.
if( ![nameLastTime isEqual: name] ) {
    // Store the new name as the name at last execution...
    CFPreferencesSetAppValue( (CFStringRef) @"name_last_execution", (CFStringRef) name, kCFPreferencesCurrentApplication );
    CFPreferencesAppSynchronize( kCFPreferencesCurrentApplication );
    [self rescheduleAllNotificationsWithUserNotification:NO];
}
```

It is not real elegant with fancy object-oriented call-back methods, etc., but it gets the job done cheaply and reliably.